# Como exibir texto vindo do mongodb (mongoose) com as quebras de linha corretamente?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express.js, mongoose

Boa tarde.
Sou iniciante e estou implementando um blog usando NodeJs + Express + MongoDb (mongoose).
Percebi que quando crio uma nova postagem, a mesma, quando é visualizada, não mostra as quebras de linha (Enter) entre os parágrafos.

Pelo que vi, ao submeter o post, este é armazenado corretamente no banco de dados. Digo, com as marcações de quebra de linha.
Pesquisei algumas possíveis soluções, mas nada do que fiz adiantou.

Aqui está o código do formulário onde o post é criado:

create.edge

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
            <form action="/posts/store" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
                        <label>Autor</label>
                        <input type="text" name="autor" placeholder="Autor" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
                        <label>Título</label>
                        <input type="text" name="titulo" placeholder="Título" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
                        <label>Descrição</label>
                        <input type="text" name="descricao" placeholder="Descrição" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
                        <label>Conteúdo</label>
                        <textarea name="conteudo" placeholder="Conteúdo..." cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <div class="form-group mt-3">
                    <input type="file" name="imagem" class="form-control-file">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group my-4 text-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Criar Postagem</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Aqui, o JS para salvar o post:

storePost.js

```
const path = require('path')

const Post = require('../database/models/Post')

module.exports = (req, res) => {
    if (req.files) {
        const {
            imagem
        } = req.files
        imagem.mv(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'public/posts', imagem.name), (error) => {
            Post.create({
                ...req.body,
                imagem: `/posts/${imagem.name}`
            }, (error, post) => {
                res.redirect('/');
            });
        })    
    } else {   
        Post.create({
            ...req.body, imagem: null }, (error, post) => {
                res.redirect('/');
        });
    }
 }
```

Aqui, um exemplo salvo no bd:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f36ef7b216f01117858a830"
    },
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2020-08-14T19:28:14.105Z"
    },
    "autor": "Marcílio",
    "titulo": "Teste",
    "descricao": "Teste",
    "conteudo": "Linha 1 (enter)\r\nLinha 2 (enter)\r\nLinha 3 (enter)",
    "imagem": null,
    "__v": 0
}
```

Como o post é exibido:

[image: Exibição do Post]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muito pesquisar e tentar manipular os arquivos vindos do banco de dados (lembrando que quando o documento era salvo no bd, este ia com as marcações \r\n referente a quebra de linha) consegui o que queria aplicando na div onde ia aparecer o documento vindo do bd o seguinte: style="white-space: pre-wrap".
Obrigado.